# How can I change the font size in this confusion matrix?

Tags: matplotlib, confusion-matrix

I have function to draw a confusion matrix

```
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_confusion_matrix(cm,classes,normalize=False,title='Confusion matrix',cmap=plt.cm.Blues):

   plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))

   plt.imshow(cm,interpolation='nearest',cmap=cmap)
   plt.title(title)
   plt.colorbar()

   tick_marks=np.arange(len(classes))
   plt.xticks(tick_marks,classes,rotation=45)
   plt.yticks(tick_marks,classes)

   if normalize:
    cm=cm.astype('float')/cm.sum(axis=1)[:,np.newaxis]
    cm=np.around(cm,decimals=2)
    cm[np.isnan(cm)]=0.0
    print('Normalized confusion matrix')

   else:
    print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')


   thresh=cm.max()/2

   for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]), range(cm.shape[1])):

    plt.text(j, i, cm[i, j],

             horizontalalignment="center",

             color="white" if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()

    plt.ylabel('True label')

    plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
```

Then, implementing the function

```
cm=confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes,y_pred)
plot_confusion_matrix(cm,target_names,title='confusion matrix')
```

Outputs this picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vVLg.png)

How can I increase the size of the numbers in the image?

Answer (score 0):

To change the font size of a matplotlib plot, you can try this approach -

```
    plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 22})
```

Moreover you can also explore other formatting options [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html)